# Guest User License - Profile

Tags: apex

I might need some clarifications regarding the profile used with 'Guest user license'.I am facing an issue with sharing 'READ' access to this profile using sharing rules and I started looking at some differences b/w this 'Guest user license' profile and other normal profiles.

> 1. I cannot see this profile listed on the page where you can view access based on a field.
> 2. There was no 'READ' access on an object on this profile but I could still see the records from this object populated in a list box on a
>      Lightning page. This makes me believe that such profile behaves
>      differently to the other profiles.

Can I someone please take some time for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

A guest user profile is designed for public users who access your community. To allow guest users to view or submit data to a standard or custom object, modify the object’s permission in the community’s guest user profile. Each community has a separate Guest User license, so you can control access to objects (including lookup fields) on a per-community basis.

It's not listed on general profile page. You need to follow this approach to reach at related guest user license: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212470&type=1

Managing the Site Guest User Profile works just like managing a standard profile with a few exceptions:

1. You can only assign the permission to read/create on standard objects, but can assign full create-read-updated-delete (CRUD) on custom objects.
2. By default, the Site Guest User does not have access to any objects, fields, or VisualForce pages. You need to enable permissions and page visibility that are applicable to your use case.
3. Once you have set permissions for the object, check out field level security to make sure that the appropriate fields are available.

Now, it is important to remember that Site Guest Users can’t be used for any purposes other than Force.com Sites. You can create up to 25 sites (Enterprise edition), which means you can create up to 25 Guest Users. These users to do not count against your purchased user limits, but you do need to monitor the profiles for all of them. If you add a custom field on the contact record that your volunteer application needs to write data to, make sure your Site Guest User has access to that field!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Why do you think the Site guest user was able to view the records he had no 'Read' access on in his profile?

Comment: I am not sure about your org configuration...that would be detailed step by step analysis....make sure there is no permission set having read permission or current object is child and master is readable...